# Java - set i to start at 0, i < arraylist.size(), i++... get out of bounds error

Tags: java, arraylist, indexing

Don't think there's much to say, here's my code

```
for (int i = 0; i < numFactors.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; i < denFactors.size(); j++) {
        if (numFactors.get(i) == denFactors.get(j)) {
            commonFactors.add(numFactors.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

And I get this error

```
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 4
    at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.creatif.cubes.Fraction.simplify(Fraction.java:64)
```

Where line 64 is at the if statement. I can't for my life find the problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inner for loop reads:

```
for (int j = 0; i < denFactors.size(); j++)
```

It's not clear that `j` will stop incrementing before it reaches `denFactors.size()`, thus the index out of bounds exception.  Did you mean:

```
for (int j = 0; j < denFactors.size(); j++)
```

Answer (score 5):

This line

```
 for (int j = 0; i < denFactors.size(); j++) {
```

should be

```
 for (int j = 0; j < denFactors.size(); j++) {
```

I believe.

--
also, you might want to call all the `.size()`'s outside of the `for`. You are calling it every time the loop runs :)

Comment: even better use for-each instead of for.